# Automate running requests in SOAP UI: How to pass a value from Java selenium code to an autoit code

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, autoit

I am working on Selenium automation and am using AutoIT to automate the non-web based actions. I need to automate running requests from SOAP UI. I have a scenario to automate in which I want to pass a value from my selenium code to AutoIT script. For an example I have a variable 'x'. I have to launch SOAP UI, create a project and pass the value of variable 'x' in the wsdl URL and run the requests. Is there a way to do this? I am assuming that launching of SOAP UI, creating project and running requests can be done by AutoIT but I am stuck at the point when I need to pass the variable 'x' in my AutoIT. Is there any way to do this? Or is there any other way to automate running requests in SOAP UI. I am using Selenium webdriver, Java and TestNG.

Answer (score 0):

You can share variables between appliations/processes many ways

- using windows messaging look up _WinAPI_PostMessage function that sends message the specific window or broadcast message to all windows so all running app gets the message (2 variables can also be passed) in autoit you can set up a function that runs (stoppping the main program) when your autoit app receives such message and variables
- you can set up UDP or TCP channels so that your running apps can communicate (UDP should work fine) one app being the server the other is the client
- file communication setup, where the variable or information to be sent is written to a file and the other app reads the file (it can be good to combine with the first method: App 'A' writes data to file 'data.msg' then sends message to App 'B' that upon receiving the message reads 'data.msg') you can establsih intricate protocol as well with Acknowladge messages etc. in case your application requires it.

_WinAPI_RegisterWindowMessage
_WinAPI_PostMessage
GUIRegisterMsg

are the relevant functions you can look them up in autoit help

If you think any of these is feasible but you need further assistance I can write a simple code that demonstrates that in practice